# non-case-sensitive sed - OpenWrt

Tags: text-processing, sed, openwrt, busybox

the input would be like this in a file:

```
<sCripT
```

and the parsing looks like this:

```
sed -i "s/<script//g" SOMETHING.html
```

the "/gi" is not good, because OpenWrt doesn't knows it (busybox..):

```
sed: bad option in substitution expression
```

Does anybody know how could i delete e.g.: the:

```
< sCripT or 
"<scRiPt"
```

with one sed?

Plus (the really thing i need): how could i delete the whole line containing

```
"<sCripT" or 
"<scRiPt", etc.?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see a way using Busybox's `sed`, but you could use Busybox's `sh` and `grep` like this:

```
while IFS='
' read -r line; do
    printf "%s\n" "$line" | grep -qi '<script' || printf "%s\n" "$line"
done <SOMETHING.html >SOMETHING.html.tmp
mv SOMETHING.html.tmp SOMETHING.html
```

Comment: Correct (after minor fixes), but overly complicated compared with [asoundmove's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10012/non-case-sensitive-sed-openwrt/10022#10022). There is a way with sed, but it's ugly: `sed -e '/<[Ss][Cc][Rr][Ii][Pp][Tt]/d'`.

Comment: @Gilles: I agree, asoundmove's is much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Does the Busybox not have `grep -v`?

This should do the job in one simple command:

```
grep -vi "<[ \t]*script" SOMETHING.html
```

Comment: Yes, Busybox has `grep -v` as a non-optional feature.